# Intent Redirection from Google Play

Tags: java, redirect, android-intent, mobile, google-play

our Application has been rejected repeatedly in recent weak because of "intent redirection".
"Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection."

and we couldn't find location of this warning .

Do you know how we could resolve this problem

please guide us to find resolution.

thanks a lot for your help.

and our code is as follows:

```
<application
android:name=".application.AppController"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
<activity android:name=".activities.IncomingCallActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
<activity android:name=".activities.ReservedTimesWebViewActivity" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.NodesLinksActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.BookmarksActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" /> <!-- To fix crash on android 9+ -->
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
        android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.PaymentCompletedActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:host="payment"
            android:pathPattern="/.*"
            android:scheme="shafadoc" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SearchActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ProfileActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.FilterActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.NodeActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ConfirmActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MapActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ReservedTimesActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.AboutActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.HelpActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ForgetPasswordActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ReservationActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.UserSelectionActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ClinicActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.AddCommentActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.UpdateActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ImageGalleryActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentCompat" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MaintenanceActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SubUserActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SupportMessageActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.DrugStoreActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.BlogPostsActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.AdActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentCompat" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.NewReservationActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.EditInsuranceActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SelectCityActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.DoctorsFilterActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ProgressActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
<activity android:name=".activities.CalendarTestActivity" />
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out ? Currently experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to add exported="false" to all activities, services and receivers if they are not supposed to be called from other apps/processes.